# Deploying Python as a single executable

Tags: python, deployment

I would like to find a way to deploy `Python` programs as an executable on Debian where I would be able to bundle:

1. the dependencies and third party libs
2. the code that might need to be installed on the host machine. Typically some libs in `Python` like `pilow` or `snappy` are depending on shared libraries within `/usr/lib`

I think you can achieve (1) and (2) separately. To achieve (1), I believe that there exists different ways to ship `virtualenv`, and for (2) I've seen some people using `Docker` image or `Ansible` to install tool/module on the host OS.

To me, it feels that by having 2 systems to achieve (1) and (2) there is a risk to have them unsynced. It feels very error prone to think that if someone adds an external dependency in its `Python` program he might also has to change a `Docker` image. So I'm wondering if there something that does both.

Answer (score 2):

I read about 2 days back about [XAR](https://code.fb.com/data-infrastructure/xars-a-more-efficient-open-source-system-for-self-contained-executables/), executable archive by FB. Have a look at [it](https://github.com/facebookincubator/xar)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two apps I know of are py2exe and PyInstaller. I'm pretty sure both support Python 3 and can store dependencies, libraries, etc. I recommend this link for more info: [Making a Stand Alone Executable from a Python Script using PyInstaller](https://medium.com/dreamcatcher-its-blog/making-an-stand-alone-executable-from-a-python-script-using-pyinstaller-d1df9170e263)

Comment: I was not really thinking of windows-executable. I'm actually deploying on Debian

Answer (score 0):

I'm achieving exactly the same with `Ansible` and `virtualenv` with a `requirements` file for Debian, MacOsX (brew) and RedHat.

As part of the playbook example:

```
  - name: Install prerequisite pip packages
    pip:
      requirements: "{{ _tmp.path }}/{{ required_pip_packages }}"
      virtualenv:  "{{ venv_dir }}"
```

Let me know if you require more information.

Comment: But then how do you deal with libs like `python-snappy` that depends on shared libraries within `/usr/lib`.  Typically before pip you need to install something on the host OS like this `sudo apt-get install -y libsnappy-dev`

Comment: Before that, I have a python script that prepares those packages (In my case git, krb, etc). Inside the same script I programmatically call the ansible yaml to continue the env preparation. I can send you some script examples if you require them.